# iOS Facebook SDK - getting user location

Tags: ios, facebook

Using `FBLoginView` I am able to log in users and get a `FBGraphUser` object which holds data in the following structure:

`FBGraphUser`
`|---username`
`|---email`
`|---id<FBGraphPlace> location`
        `|---place_name`
        `|---id<FBGraphLocation> location`
                `|---city`
                `|---street`
                `|---latitude/longitude`
See Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphUser/) for a better picture :)

I am able to get user's `FBGraphPlace location` with correct `place_name` data but the `FBGraphLocation` comes null.

I'd like access to this data, and this is where I'm stumped. I ensured the user's location information is publicly visible, and I set the `readPermissions` of `FBLoginView` to include `@"user_location"`.

Does anyone know where I could be making my mistake? Thanks!

**Edit - Solution:** My Facebook address field was empty. I mistook *'current city'* for address.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: @Bibo Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
id<FBGraphUser> fbUser = (id<FBGraphUser>)user;
id<FBGraphPlace> fbPlace = [fbUser location];
id<FBGraphLocation> fbLocation = [fbPlace location];
NSString * userCity = [fbLocation city];
NSString * userCountry = [fbLocation country];
NSString * userZip = [fbLocation zip];
```

You are currently accessing the name property of the FBGraphPlace which is giving you an NSString representation of the place. What you want to do instead is access the location property which is an FBGraphLocation. This object has properties for the various components you want.

But i'm not sure this is what you need.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying - good point. Unfortunately, this still yields nulls for `fbLocation`, and all it's components. Are you getting correct data using this code?

Comment: Yes and no, check using your own Facebook account, you have to give your complete address to Facebook (i tested it with my account an the code is ok, the problem is the data you get from Facebook and the users, is not related to the permissions), if you does not get any value is because is not complete in Facebook, i think that there is nothing we can do to get that information from all users, i'm facing the same problem in my app

Comment: Your insights helped me solve it - Thank you very much! I was naive and was only filling out my personal 'current city'. Based on your last comment, _"give your complete address to Facebook"_, I looked further and found there is an address field which was empty for my personal account. Filled out, it yields correct results. Again, thanks!

Comment: looks like `FBGraphUser` has been removed in the latest version of FB SDK